# My Cpu was damaged, How can I tell whether my motherboard is dead or not?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have an Asus prime a320m-k board and a few days ago I accidentally damaged my ryzen 3 1200 processor.

I was cleaning my PC and accidentally bent a few pins of the processor and broke one too. Now that my CPU is damaged, I want to check if my board is dead or not. When I connect everything in place, the lights of my keyboard and mouse still starting glowing once I turn the power supply on.

The Power button doesn't work which is not surprising as the CPU is dead. However, the lights on the motherboard don't turn on(they used to turn on as soon as power was detected) but I know the motherboard is still receiving power and sending it via USB ports as mouse and keyboard lights work.

My motherboard should be fine right? I don't really know when the orange lights on the motherboard turn on but I guess they turn on when a processor is detected as they never turned on without a processor before. So, I hope my motherboard is fine as I already ordered a Ryzen 3 1300x.

If someone can help me out with this, I'll be glad. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious: what was the reason for removing your CPU while cleaning?

Comment: Actually I wasn't going to remove it either, but it was stuck to the heatsink due to the thermal paste and it came out with the heatsink, then while taking it off the heatsink, I accidentally dropped it and it got damaged.

Comment: We can pontificate on what we think may or may not have happened, but it's based on what you tell us.  If the CPU got pulled out and then you dropped the CPU and damaged it, why would you think there might be something wrong with the motherboard?  It isn't logical that it would be affected by the mishap with the CPU, but is there any other reason to suspect a problem?  Why did you pull things apart to clean it?  Are you concerned you might have damaged something while cleaning it?

Comment: @fixer1234 no I didn't do anything that could possibly damage the motherboard, but I did put the damaged CPU on it so I thought it might've been damaged but now I think it's fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, just got my new CPU, placed it in, fixed the heatsink, and voila! Everything works now. The motherboard was fine. Found out the lights on the board light up only when a CPU is detected as I was suspecting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the motherboard should be fine. What you're noticing is the computer turning on but not posting, because your CPU isn't connected to the motherboard.

Comment: Well, I get no response by pressing the power button at all, no fans start up. Could this be another problem created by the CPU? Also, assuming my motherboard is fine, can keeping my damaged CPU in it for more time damage the socket too? As it doesn't settle down properly.

Comment: Yea dude, I would NOT put that broke CPU on the motherboard and power it on. Just wait till you get the new CPU. I understand you're probably freaking out about the whole situation. But this is all pointless until you get a new CPU to know if the motherboard works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Some motherboards have self-diagnostic signals :

- with a seven-segment display on the card itself
- with a range of 4 diagnostic LEDs
- or with a series of beeps at power on

Have a look at the manual coming with your hardware for the meaning of these "error codes", and check whether the alert you get is something like "CPU not found".

> absolutely nothing happens when I press the power button as I don't think this motherboard even starts the computer unless CPU is detected.

What happens when a motherboard gets the "start" signal (when you press the power button) :

- it forwards this signal to the power supply
- the power supply starts
- the motherboards waits some milliseconds so that the power supply reaches its "Ready" status (CPUs and the like require steady volts and amps !)
- once the power is ok, the motherboard "wakes up" by powering its own subparts : CPU, memory, buses, drives, ...
- when everybody is powered, the BIOS "POST" (power-on self test) starts. This is where everything is checked, and reported as OK or not.
- if everything is OK, the BIOS has instructions (hardcoded address, actually) where it'll read the next pieces of code to actually boot the operating system.

**SOME** manufacturers implement warning features (with beeps or LEDs) during the early tests when something is wrong. Looks like your motherboard has no such feature.

However, the fact that there's nothing to see when you press the power button (no fan spinning) does NOT mean it's dead (and so far -given the facts- you can't know). But I guess everything will be fine when you'll receive your new CPU.

Comment: The motherboard speaker and all the wirings have been done properly and double checked by me. But absolutely nothing happens when I press the power button as I don't think this motherboard even starts the computer unless CPU is detected.